# Java hexadecimal base double literal

Tags: java, hex, literals

I am studying for java certification. And i'm curious about the java literals.
I know it is possible to do something like this:

```
int i = 0xAA;
long l = 0xAAL;
```

Also this is possible for floating-point variables:

```
double d = 123d;
float f = 123f;
```

So I logically thought with these examples that the same would apply for hexadecimal.  Just like i can add L for long literals, I could add 'd' or 'f' but the logic is flawed since 'F' and 'D' are valid hexadecimal values.

It is not possible to do something like this:

```
double d = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAd;
```

Is this just not allowed by Java or there is a simple way to do it that I don't know?

Comment: Do you understand IEEE-754 floating point format? Did you study the Java language reference documentation? What do you expect is the floating point value of `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`?

Comment: @JimGarrison: The OP says "It is not possible" which suggests they have indeed tried and found it gives an error. I wasn't aware of floating-point hex literals in Java myself until I started answering the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's interesting....

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I have studied the java documentation, but I didn't try this specific case, since the exam may ask anything that is possible or not, I had to understand that too. I had the notion about the floating point format, but thanks for the IEEE reference.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It turns out it *is* possible, although that surprised me. [Section 3.10.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) gives the structure of floating point literals, including *HexadecimalFloatingPointLiteral*.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d1 = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAp0d;
        double d2 = 0x1.8p1d;

        System.out.println(d1); // A very big number
        System.out.println(d2); // 24 = 1.5 * 2^1
    }
}
```

The `p` is required as part of the binary exponent - the value after the `p` is the number of bits to shift the value left. Other examples:

```
0x1.4p0d => 1.25 (binary 0.01 shifted 0 bits)
0x8p-4d => 0.5 (binary 1000 shifted *right* 4 bits)
```

Comment: It turns out to be a quite difficult-to-read literal, but it is possible indeed!

Comment: C has hexadecimal floating-point constants, with similar syntax, added in C99.

Comment: @KeithThompson -- yeah, the syntax was originally adopted for C99 AFAICT and then migrated to other languages in the C-family as well as Python and some others from there.  (They're useful in low-level numerics code where bitwise-exact FP values are needed.)

Comment: And in case it's not obvious. hexadecimal floating-point uses `p` (perhaps for "point"?)  to introduce the exponent (rather than the `e` used for decimal floating-point) because `e` is also a hexadecimal digit. And the exponent part is mandatory to avoid ambiguity with an `f` suffix used to indicate a constant of type `float`.

Comment: Great answer. Much more helpful than Jim Garrison's trolly whine. Thank you!